# UWP Deployment Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7 not found error

Tags: deployment, uwp, appx

I have recently installed a few updates to windows / visual studio 2017, and now when I create a package of my UWP app and try deploying it to any of the machine where it used to work just fine - installation fails and there is this error message in windows error log:

```
AppX Deployment operation failed for package 92211ab1-5481-4a1a-9111-a3dd87b81b72_1.0.26.0_neutral_~_n78qa84z3g9aj with error 0x80073CF3. The specific error text for this failure is: Windows cannot install package 92211ab1-5481-4a1a-9111-a3dd87b81b72_1.0.26.0_x86__n78qa84z3g9aj because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 1.7.25531.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7" currently installed are: {}
```

I can not find any reference on the web for this package.

The package installs just fine on the developement machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

Screenshot of my dependencies folder below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UWP Deployment Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7 not found

The problem is that there is no `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7` dependence in current OS system. And you could install `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7` dependence manually.

The `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7` dependence will be stored in the `Dependencies` folder where under the appx folder.
[image]

**Update1**

I have checked your screenshot. It seems that you generate your package in debug mode and I can reproduce the same dependency in this way. The .NET Native tool chain is checked by default in the release mode. So you could regenerate your package in **release mode** to get files above.

Comment: Thanks for your response! These packages are missign from the dependencies folder (screenshot in my original post). Is there a place where I can find them on my local machine or download them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these dependencies only appear on a Release build, and not in Debug.